# How to check Status of login window/screen on osx

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have written following code for showing login window/screen.

```
system("/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend");
```

this is working fine. Is it possible to detect whether this screen disappeared or not(i.e. it will disappear when user will login again)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"com.apple.sessionDidMoveOffConsole" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSLog(@"user inactive");
    }];

    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"com.apple.sessionDidMoveOnConsole" object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        NSLog(@"user active");
    }];
}
```

**EDIT**

I found that by subscribing to all distributed notifications and find the ones that occur in this right moment and reduced them step by step to these remaining two.

I'm note 100% sure it'll work without issues. I couldn't find any documentation on this so you might need to test test test and search the edge cases.

Comment: @FaisalIkwal: Welcome! Nice I could help. Please read my edit; this is no officially documented variant, so we don't know the edge cases.

Comment: But googling turned nothing out except fast user switching, so I'd bet it'll work